# Javascript sort table inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, tablesorter

I would like to sort some data that I am sending via "tableCells" object, using props.

```
const tableColumns = [
  'Número do Bloco',
  'Andar do apartamento',
  'Número do apartamento',
  'Tamanho do apartamento',
  'Número da vaga',
  'Ações',
];
```

Getting all the cells information via map, as follow.
How could I sort each column triggered by user click?

```
        <TableRow>
          {props.tableCells
            ? props.tableCells.map((tableCellContent) => (
                <TableCell
                  align='center'
                  className={classes.tableCellAdjustment}
                >
                  {document[tableCellContent]}
                </TableCell>
              ))
            : ''}
          <TableCell
            align='center'
            className={classes.tableCellAdjustment}
          >
            <Fab
              color='default'
              aria-label='edit'
              size='small'
              className={classes.marginAdjustment}
            >
              <EditIcon />
            </Fab>
            <Fab
              color='default'
              aria-label='delete'
              size='small'
              className={classes.marginAdjustment}
            >
              <DeleteIcon
              //onClick={() => this.props.deleteLine(document)}
              />
            </Fab>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
```